# angular strap bs-select puts checkmark on newline

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hello I am trying to use angular-strap to put together a multiselect drop down menu. For testing, I am just putting in some dummy data like so. THe issue is that the check mark on selected items displays on almost new line. I am not sure how to go about fixing it.

{value:'BLAH.09', label:'BLAH.09    '}

Couple of things to keep in mind: 
1. The extra spaces in label are just a part of the troubleshooting process, it still doesn't work if they are there. 
2. The reason the box is so wide in the screenshot is because I manually adjusted the width in css to see if it makes a difference, it doesn't..

Button looks like this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model="selectedIcons" data-html="1" placeholder="Category Filter" data-multiple="1" data-animation="am-flip-x" ng-options="val.value for val in display_data['fields']" bs-select> Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: any chance of a plunker or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Was missing an include to the main.min.css file.